# How to set multiple alarms with Thingsboard Rule chain

Tags: alarm, rule-engine, thingsboard

I have to set more than 10 different types of alarms from the same device. Do I have to create multiple chains for each alarm type, as in the picture below, or there is another way to do it simpler?

[image: Rule chain alarms]

Answer (score 0):

Here is a slightly simpler variant that only needs one script node. We still need two alarm nodes (1 for create and 1 for clear) for each alarm type though.

[image: Thingsboard Rule chain with multiple alarms]

The alarm rule can use information from the metadata, so if only one alarm is ever active at the same time, it is possible to use a single create alarm node and a single clear alarm node.

I wish the alarm rule could use the output from the previous link because that would allow use of a single create alarm node and a single clear alarm node for multiple alarms as well.